# Проблема пакетов при обновлении MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal

При обновлении `Mysql` возникла такая проблема.
Зависимости пакетов которые не устанавливаются и не удаляются.

Вот ошибка после работы команды `apt-get -f install`.

> dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.6.38-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    попытка перезаписать общий «/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18/changelog.Debian.gz», который отличается от других экземпляров пакета libmysqlclient18:amd64
>   При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.6.38-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

А вот это ошибка при работе команды `apt-get autoremove`.

> Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install».
>   Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
>    libmysqlclient-dev : Зависит: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.6.38-1ubuntu14.04) но 5.6.37-1ubuntu14.04 уже установлен
>    libmysqlclient18 : Ломает: libmysqlclient18:i386 (!= 5.6.37-1ubuntu14.04) но 5.6.38-1ubuntu14.04 уже установлен
>    libmysqlclient18:i386 : Ломает: libmysqlclient18 (!= 5.6.38-1ubuntu14.04) но 5.6.37-1ubuntu14.04 уже установлен
>   E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь использовать -f.

Как можно устранить это ошибку и как то нормально установить или хоть удалить эти пакеты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo rm libmysqlclient18_5.6.38-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```

Грубо говоря у вас зависшие пакеты, надо ручками их вычистить, потом заново подтянуть зависимости

Comment: Выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: А попробуйте просто всю папку cache очистить

Comment: Все та же ошибка, не как это не помогает

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan а если так полностью снести все, а потом переустановить? apt-get –purge remove mysql-server
apt-get –purge remove mysql-client
apt-get –purge remove mysql-common
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean